# the project title not appear at the top of activity with relative layout

Tags: android

android:label="hi"

the project title not appear at the top of activity with relative layout
what the problem , why title not appear

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="Battery Information"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Extra Level"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You applied the theme of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.  You have to change that to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.You can get this on `values->styles` file.Then you can able to see the title bar on the top.

for example

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

You should change `NoActionBar` into `DarkACtionBar`.I hope this will solve your issue

Comment: It actually wasDarkActionBar

Comment: solved by make activity inherits from AppCompatActivity